# python panda query not able to process date value

Tags: python, dataframe, date

I read data from csv file which has Time column values as '22-02-21' format.

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',parse_dates=['Time'])
    
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Time column info shows Time as non-null  datetime64[ns]

I need to pass 2 times to get the rows matching the data. I am not able to pass "Time" in one query

```
df2 = df.query('Column1 =="value" & Column2 =="abc" & `C Type`=="type" ')
filtered=df2.query("Time =='2023-01-02'")
```

Can someone help me understand why and how to pass in one query instead of 2?

I tried various combinations of passing variables. Such as: `Time =="2023-01-26"'` in the query.

```
df2 = df.query((f'column1=="value" & Column2 =="abc" & `C Type`=="type" & Time =="2022-01-26"'))
print (" Test ********** Sum:",sum(df2['Measure'])) 
Sum:0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why yours doesn't work. It worked fine for me.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Time": ["22-02-21", "23-02-21", "24-02-21", "25-02-21", "26-02-21"],
        "Temperature": [20, 20, 22, 23, 24],
        "City": ["London", "London", "London", "London", "London"],
    }
)
# format was wrong need %y not %Y
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format="%y-%m-%d")

df2 = df.query('Temperature ==20 & City =="London" & Time == "2022-02-21"')
print(df2)
```

One thing that was off in your code is the format was wrong for your conversion to datetimes. You need a `%y` not `%Y`

Comment: Thank you very much. correcting the format worked, not sure how it worked in the second case not in the first case along with rest of the query parameters.